# Poincare Plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to perform a List Plot, but I'm having an issue trying to plot the two given functions accordingly. What is the syntax suppose to look like for Sow within the WhenEvent function?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
q = 0.2; \[Omega] = 2.44; \[Beta] = 0.03; m = 3.2; \[Kappa] = 2.63; \
\[CapitalOmega] = 2.4; 
sol = Reap[NDSolveValue[{
    f''[t] + 2 \[Beta] f'[t] + (1 - m \[Omega]^2 u[t]) f[t] == 0,
    u''[t] + 
      2 \[Beta] u[t] + \[Omega]^2 u[
        t] + \[Kappa] (f[t]*f''[t] + (f'[t])^2) == 
     q/m Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t],
    f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]/\[CapitalOmega]] == 0, 
     Sow[{f[t], f'[t]}, {u[t], u'[t]}]]}
   , {f, u}, {t, 0, 30000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]
ListPlot[pst, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0025], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What is `pst` in the `ListPlot`?

Comment: That was meant to be my list of points, but I changed the variable for the NDSolveValue setup to see what came out of it without problems regarding the list shapes not matching

Comment: `Plot[sol[[1, 2]][x], {x, 0, 30000}]`?

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work :(